# how to get X window id of a window created by glut

Tags: x11, glut

I created a window using glutCreateWindow( window_name);
How can I get the X window id of this window?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLUT intentionally does not make this information available, in order to maintain maximal windowing system neutrality.

You might be able to work around this restriction by creating a window, then immediately calling `glXGetCurrentDrawable()`. This returns a `GLXDrawable`. For GLUT windows, this is *probably* the same as the underlying Xlib `Window`. I have tested this on my system and it seems to be working, but YMMW.